Search (lowcode) Web Frontend working with REST-Calls for Data-Interactions
I am looking for a web frontend that fetches and writes data via rest calls.
The following main criteria:

preferably LowCode or Python, fast from prototype to application
preferably well-known solutions / no special unknown products
no Java, no PHP (and preferably no javascript/typescript)
no programming of user interface interactions, effects, widgets, and themes (like jquery etc.)
data only REST-based / database-less
must support login and ACLs based on users and groups (rest or ldap based)
Forwarding user creds to rest backend
user-dependent menus
Main Task - View/edit/Update data in tables/forms and ACL based view/edit (data/content/changes via REST from/to backend via webhooks)
Templates for document display on website
Flexible input/value validation, ideally with RegEx

In the area of databases, NocoDb would come close.
Does anyone have any good ideas?
